# customize datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is bound to a datatable containing 3 columns namely, CREAT, Type, RecordDate.

I want datagridview to have two columns, one of the columns should be like CREAT (Type) and second columns is RecordDate.
How can I accomplish this
I tried doing like this, but it did not work out.

```
    dgvCreatinine.DataSource = Nothing
    dgvCreatinine.ColumnCount = 2
    dgvCreatinine.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = String.Format("{0} ({1})", "CREAT", "Type")
    dgvCreatinine.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = String.Format("{0}", "RecordDate")
    dgvCreatinine.DataSource = dtTemp
    dgvCreatinine.Height = dgvCreatinine.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow).First().Height * dtTemp.Rows.Count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a calculated column to your datatable and display that one.
`dtTemp.columns.Add("Test", GetType(String), String.Format("{0} + ' (' + {1} + ')'", "CREAT", "Type"))`